Novel about a girl encountering one or more witches, "pigeon sisters"?. You can identify a witch by their ability to put their chin on their chest
This was a paperback book in my grandparents' house, which means that there are good odds that the book comes from somewhere in the 1950s to 1960s, since most of the books there belong to my uncles and aunts, although I think I read it somewhere in the late 1980s to the early 1990s, in Louisville Kentucky if that makes a difference. The protagonist, I think a girl, encounters one or more witches in an old house. I vaguely remember that the witches wore dresses made out of feathers, although I might be conflating that with The Witches of Worm. The part that is really stuck with me over the years was that one of the traits that let you identify somebody as a witch was that they could put their chin on their chest. I remember in part because, as a kid, I practiced until I could do that. The witches may have been named the Pigeon Sisters although I don't recall why. I do remember that the girl was trapped in the house with the witches, and had to find a way to escape before she was trapped forever. I don't remember it being an especially long book, probably between a hundred and 200 pages at the most. There were some line and ink drawings inside, including one showing one of the witches placing her hooked chin on her chest, her eyes gazing down at the proof of her witchiness. I have a vague memory that the cover might have depicted the house that the witches were in.

The Wicked Pigeon Ladies in the Garden (AKA The Wicked, Wicked Ladies in the Haunted House) by Mary Chase. It was published in 1968.

Maureen Swanson is the scourge of the neighborhood. At age nine, she
already has a reputation as a hard slapper, a loud laugher, a liar,
and a stay-after-schooler. The other kids call her Stinky. So
sometimes when Maureen passes the crumbling (and haunted?) Messerman
mansion, she imagines that she is Maureen Messerman–rich, privileged,
and powerful. Then she finds a way into the forbidden, boarded-up
house. In the hall are portraits of seven young women wearing
elaborate gowns and haughty expressions. Maureen has something
scathing to say to each one, but then she notices that the figures
seem to have shifted in their frames. So she reaches out her finger to
touch the paint–just to make sure–and touches . . . silk! These seven
daughters of privilege are colder and meaner than Maureen ever thought
to be. They are wicked, wicked ladies, and Maureen has something they
want. . . .


Huh. I think that is definitely the one that I was remembering in regards to them being called pigeon sisters, but a text search in the internet archive copies doesn't seem to support my memory of the chin and the chest. A mystery for another time...

Also the author of Harvey
